# task scheduler returns false executing the script

Tags: powershell, network-share, task-scheduler

The following script checks for network share availability:

```
while($true)
{
    $i++
    test-path Z: |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} | Out-File "F:\script\path.log" -Append
    Start-Sleep -s 5
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
True
```

**Executing from task scheduler as same user returns false**.
What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, the Task Scheduler doesn't know the environment variablessuch as "Z:".
Testing with the Fully Qualified network share name make it work.